# Copying into a variable with larger size

Tags: c++, memcpy

I have a large array of type `uint8_t (uint8_t mydata[1000])`. I just want to copy 4 byte length data from this large array. Is it okay if I copy 4 bytes of data into 64 bit integer variable? or should I define destination variable as 4 byte length like `uint32_t`?

```
uint8_t mydata[1000];

uint64_t mysentS; //Is this okay when coping 4 bytes of data or should it be uint32_t?
uint64_t mysentUS;

memcpy(&mysentS, &mydata[16], 4);
memcpy(&mysentUS, &mydata[20], 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's okay as in "it won't crash", but it's pretty scary code.

Assuming the location in the character array contains a 32-bit integer in 4 `char`s, that you want to use as an integer, you run into [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues that you need to deal with it.

It's not clear that copying into the "first" (address-wise) bytes of the `uint64_t` gets you the value you want, that depends on the endianness of the current machine.

On a little-endian machine it will work, but on a big-endian machine it won't.

It's better to extract the value byte-by-byte, since then you can be explicit about what you want each byte to signify.

```
/* Extract 32-bit little-endian value. */
mysentS = (mydata[16] << 0)  + (mydata[17] << 8) +
          (mydata[18] << 16) + (mydata[19] << 24);
```

This works since the shift expressions have their left-hand sides promoted to `unsigned int` before the shift is applied.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you will copy 4 bytes of integer with sign to integer without sign or if you will skip endiannes (if any used) you will get different result than you should have. For compiler it looks ok.